# Laravel how to sum values in related table and add the value to the object and order by the sum value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables "inventory" and "deliver_record". Table relations are inventory->hasMany(deliver_record).
I need to take the values of deliver_record units and sum them, and then add the sum to the inventory object. After this, we need to order by the sum value in the inventory object.

Right now the object looks like this:

```
Inventory {#641 ▼
  #table: "inventory"
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:21 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "client_id" => 52
    "sku_number" => null
    "upc_number" => ""
    "product_number" => "217353"
    "other_product_numbers" => "BR0017"
    "brand" => "Britpart"
    "supplier" => "Bearmach"
    "storage_location" => "A2"
    "title" => "HUB LOCKING WASHER SERIES 1 - 111 - DEFENDER - RANGE ROVER CLASSIC."
    "images" => "a:1:{i:0;s:19:"217353-WJjyBPGK.jpg";}"
    "weight" => 0
    "weight_unit" => "lb"
    "height" => 0
    "width" => 0
    "length" => 0
    "dimension_unit" => "in"
    "stock_level" => 5
    "part_type" => "Genuine"
    "created_at" => "2017-06-21 13:29:11"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-23 18:10:38"
  ]
  #original: array:21 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "deliveryRecord" => Collection {#958 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▼
        0 => DeliveryRecord {#972 ▼
          #table: "inventory_delivery_records"
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:11 [▼
            "id" => 4
            "client_id" => 0
            "product_id" => 3
            "price_original" => "0.14"
            "price_original_currency" => "GBP"
            "price" => "0.19"
            "price_currency" => "USD"
            "units" => 110
            "conv_rate" => "1.3500"
            "created_at" => "2018-08-23 23:00:00"
            "updated_at" => "2018-08-23 23:00:00"
          ]
          #original: array:11 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
        }
        1 => DeliveryRecord {#970 ▼
          #table: "inventory_delivery_records"
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:11 [▼
            "id" => 3616
            "client_id" => 0
            "product_id" => 3
            "price_original" => "0.15"
            "price_original_currency" => "GBP"
            "price" => "0.20"
            "price_currency" => "USD"
            "units" => 20
            "conv_rate" => "1.3100"
            "created_at" => "2019-10-20 00:42:19"
            "updated_at" => "2019-10-20 00:42:19"
          ]
          #original: array:11 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
        }
        2 => DeliveryRecord {#966 ▶}
        3 => DeliveryRecord {#968 ▶}
        4 => DeliveryRecord {#967 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "orderInRecord" => Collection {#1194 ▶}
    "sellRecord" => Collection {#1673 ▶}
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

How can I sum values of the relational table and then order the whole inventory by the sum?

Answer (score 0):

you may use some thing like ...

in Controller

```
return $inventory->append('deliverySum');
```

Now in Inventory Model do

```
public function getDeliverySumAttribute()
{
    $sum = 0;
    $this->deliverRecord->each(function (DeliverRecord $deliverRecord)use(&$sum) {
        $sum +=   $deliverRecord->sum;
    });

    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me. I think it is the most performant approach:

```php
Inventory::addSelect([
    'units_total' => DeliveryRecord::selectRaw("SUM(units)")->whereColumn(
        'inventory_id',
        'inventories.id'
    )
])
    ->orderBy('units_total', 'DESC')

    ->get();
```